# Variable scope in objects

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to teach myself some better JS development practice, so I'm writing my latest VLE widget in a JavaScript object wrapper.

```
var TutorGroupPoints = {
    URL: 'http://staff.curriculum.local/frog/rewards.php',
    CurrentUser: UWA.Environment.user.id,
    Groups: { },
    Sorted: [ ],

    init: function() {
        /* retrieve all of the groups from Frog and store them in a variable */
        Frog.API.get('groups.getAll',
        {
            'onSuccess': function (data) { this.Groups = data; },
            'onError': function(err) { alert(err); }
        });         
    },

    yearClick: function(year) {
        alert( this.Groups );

        for (var i = 0; i < this.Groups.length; i++) {

            if (this.Groups[i].name.indexOf(year) == 0 && this.Groups[i].name.indexOf('/Tp') != -1) {
                var arrayToPush = { 'id': this.Groups[i].id, 'name': this.Groups[i].name };
                this.Sorted.push(arrayToPush);
            }
        }
    }

};

widget.onLoad = function(){
    TutorGroupPoints.init();

    $('#nav li a').click(function() {
        TutorGroupPoints.yearClick($(this).attr("id"));
    });
}
```

The `Frog.API` call retrieves information about students/staff from our VLE (Virtual Learning Environment).

What I'm trying to do is store this information (retrieved in a variable called `data`) in a class-scope variable for use with other functions.

I thought I'd done that by declaring the `Groups` variable early on then using `data = this.Groups`, but then when I run the `yearClick` function, `this.Groups` simply appears as `[object Object]` where `data` alerts as loads of objects, i.e. `[object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object]`.

When I change `Groups` to `[ ]`, the alert is entirely empty.

As such, I'm guessing that this is a scope problem. How can I store `data` from the `Frog.API` call in a variable which I can use with other functions? Previously I've just used functions, i.e. `'onSuccess': function (data) { someOtherFunction(data); },` but I don't think that's a very clean or practical way of doing it?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common mistake. Your success callback, being a function, changes the `this` context that code executes in. So in your callback, `this` no longer points to the `TutorGroupPoints` object.

Either cache a reference to the outer `this` outside the function...

```
init: function() {
    var that = this; // <-- caching outer this
    Frog.API.get('groups.getAll', {
        'onSuccess': function (data) { that.Groups = data; },
        'onError': function(err) { alert(err); }
    });         
}
```

or bind a copy of it passed in via a closure, in this case an immediately-executing function

```
init: function() {
    Frog.API.get('groups.getAll', {
        'onSuccess': (function(that) {
             return function (data) { that.Groups = data; }
        })(this), // <-- passing reference to outer this
        'onError': function(err) { alert(err); }
    });         
}
```

Comment: Not sure who won this time - they both say "2 mins ago". Perhaps we should draw up a shifts rota :)

Comment: FWIW, the `this` problem is _nothing_ to do with the call being asynchronous.  It's the fact that it uses an inner function.

Comment: Mine was definitely first, by about 15 seconds.  I saw mine say 1 minute ago when yours said 44 seconds

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. One thing though - how will `this.Groups` then be accessible to other functions? Surely now only `that.Groups` has actually been changed, rather than the object's `Groups` variable which I'm trying to use in other functions?

Comment: `that.Groups` (I wouldn't capitalise it - it's not a class) is a *reference to*, not a *copy of*, `TutorGroupPoints.Groups`, so they are one and the same, so no issue here.

Comment: Ahah, working perfectly. Thanks for the explanation. Is there a common naming practice for variables/functions etc. in JavaScript that I could read up on somewhere?

Comment: Yes - many of them different and contradictory. The main ones are: 1) capitalisation for constructors; 2) underscore prefixes for local, private variables. Douglas Crockford has a piece online somewhere about good code layout, and this sort of thing.

Comment: @Utkanos but note that many of Doug's "style rules" are just his personal preference.

Comment: @Alnitak - that goes without saying. The code will work whatever your naming conventions - suggestions are just that, suggestions.

Comment: @Utkanos that's the problem - people read too much into some of his "suggestions".  Some are founded in good CS principles.  Others are just style, but he doesn't distinguish the two.

Answer (score 1):

Your `this` variable is wrong inside the Frog callback.  Use this instead:

```
init: function() {
    var self = this;  // reference for use inside closures
    /* retrieve all of the groups from Frog and store them in a variable */
    Frog.API.get('groups.getAll',
    {
        'onSuccess': function (data) { self.Groups = data; },
        'onError': function(err) { alert(err); }
    });         
}
```

Any time a function is called it is supplied a context (i.e. `this`).  Inside your callback your `this` value is probably the global `window` object.  Using the cached variable ensures that the original (outer) `this` is still accessible inside the closure.